# @Autowired or private final

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My question is simple. Which approach is more efficient?

method 1:

```
 @Autowired
 private CustomerRepository customerRepo;
```

method 2:

```
private final CustomerRepository custormerRepo;
 
public StudentService(CustomerRepository customerRepo) {
         this.customerRepo = customerRepo;
}
```

As I see  the DI in the method2 is more recent. But I wanted to ask you which one should I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Method 2 is much more flexible.

Method 1 is an example of field injection and method 2 is an example of constructor injection.

Field injection has some drawbacks that constructor injection avoids. Here are some advantages of constructor injection:

**Immutability:**

You can't do this is plain Java:

```java
@Autowired
private final CustomerRepository customerRepo;

// No constructor that sets "customerRepo".
```

So, Spring offers constructor injection:

```java
private final CustomerRepository customerRepo;

@Autowired
public StudentService(final CustomerRepository customerRepo) {
  this.customerRepo = customerRepo;
}
```

Immutability is sometimes preferred. One reason is that it helps with thread-safety. Another is security.

Personally, I follow the rule, "if it can be final, it should be final." **EDIT 23-05-23:** This rule doesn't make sense if you are writing a library, since you want functionality to be easily extended and changed.

**Testing:**

You won't need reflection to set the dependencies. Yes, many mocking frameworks handle this for you, but with constructor injection, you have the option to call `new` on the constructor.

**Nasty `NullPointerException`s:**

An object is created by calling its constructor, right? We usually want our arguments to be non-null at the time they are passed in. With constructor injection, the [Spring IoC container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) makes sure that all the arguments passed in the constructor are available before passing them into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In your main code, you should use method 2 as field injection (method 1) is not recommended. (see [here](https://cloudolife.com/2021/02/27/Programming-Language/Java/FAQs/Field-injection-is-not-recommended-and-Injection-guidelines-in-Java-Spring/) for reasons)

In your test code, it's okay to use method 1.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you suggest something better. By using the Lombok library's `@RequiredArgConstructor` you are thus avoiding the boilerplate code. and if you wonder why `@Autowired` not recommended , because of when you want to write unit testing in your application and there will be problem , where if you use `@Autowired`.

Comment: We can mock the dependencies which are used with `@Autowired` right?

Answer (score 0):

use constructor injection, Spring also recommends it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what the other answers have said about immutability, another benefit of constructor injection is to be able to avoid NPE is the field is not initialized. Using autowired, from a test, you’d create the class and then must remember to set the field. Using constructor injection, you can’t not initialize the field. This is more prominent in Kotlin where autowired fields are declared as `lateinit var` and throw a runtime exception if used before initialized. But a constructor argument can be declared as not null type which prevents you from even explicitly passing null.